# How can I select a tab from the YUI TabView without clicking it based on URL arguments

Tags: javascript, events, tabs, yui, click

I'm using the YUI TabView tab system.

I want to be able to select a certain tab from this TabView without having to click it. I want it to automatically open based on arguments I'll pass via URL.

I need to know what YUI event to call to make this happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set the tab using the 'set' method:

```
myTabs.set("activeTab", tabInstance);
```

where myTabs is the tabset, and tabInstance is the tab you are going to make active.